# Restoring state with certain fields marked as transient

Tags: java, android, serialization, constructor, transient

I have a number of serializable objects I'd like to save and restore from file. The problem is, a number of objects contain transient fields that are initialised in the constructor and then used by methods of the same class.

So, some fields cannot be restored, but need to be reinitialised.

Illustrative example:

```
private transient Paint myPaint;

public MyClass() {
    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
}

public void Render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText("Text: ", 0, 0, myPaint);
}
```

What's a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of fields that are transient you could create your own proxy class with a list of those fields and a Paint object. For example proxy.setAntiAlias(true) would set proxy's field antiAlias to true and also pass that value to paint:

```
public class Proxy
    implements Serializable
{
    transient Paint paint;

    public Proxy(Paint paint)
    {
        this.paint = paint;
    }

    public Paint getPaint()
    {
        return paint;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean antiAlias)
    {
        this.antiAlias = antiAlias;
        getPaint().setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
    }

    public boolean getAntiAlias()
    {
        return antiAlias;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
        getPaint().setColor(color);
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Then your code:

```
private transient Paint myPaint;

public MyClass(Proxy proxy) {
    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setAntiAlias(proxy.getAntiAlias());
    myPaint.setColor(proxy.getColor());
}

public void Render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText("Text: ", 0, 0, myPaint);
}
```

When you want to save paint's configuration then you could serialize the object proxy and restore paint's configuration from using proxy object.